# Computing network properties for subset of nodes

Tags: pandas, networkx

**Context:** I have two panda dataframes that characterize a network, `df_nodes` and `df_edges`. They can be matched through a shared identfier, `id`.

`df_nodes` looks roughly like this:

```
    id:     att_1:   att_2:  att_3:
    id1     red       ...    ...
    id2     red       ...    ...
    id3     blue      ...    ...
```

`df_edges`characterizes a (weighted) directed network, but I am interested in the (weighted) undirected representation for now.

```
   id_from: id_to:   weight:  
    id1     id2        0.5    .
    id1     id3        0.2      
    id2     id4        0.4
```

Two features are as follows:

- The same node sometimes appears the `id_from` column and at other times in `id_to` (in the example, this would be `id_4`; in practice there are millions of edges).
- More importantly, `df_edges` includes connections to nodes that are *not* in `df_nodes`, ie I don't have any attribute data for those.

**Objective:** I would like to create a `nx.Graph()` object that only includes edges between those nodes for which I have attributes data, ie which are in `df_nodes`. I then want to add (selected) attributes data in `df_nodes`, and compute statistics such as the average (standard deviation, ...) weighted degree for the group of nodes with some attribute value (eg where `df_nodes[att_1]='red'`).

**Approach thus far**: I am new to network analysis, so probably what I'm doing is misguided.
I first create `G`

```py
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_edges, 'id_from', 'id_to', 'weight', nx.Graph())
```

then tried adding the attribute of interest

```py
nx.set_node_attributes(G, df_nodes[['id','att_1',]].set_index('id').to_dict('index'),'id')
```

I thought I could then use something like the following to filter out the nodes that meet an attribute value.

```py
nodes_subset = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True) if y['att_1']='red']
```

But (i) doing so throws a key error, presumably because many nodes don't even have `att_1`, and (ii) the approach seems very inefficient.

I'd be very grateful for any help on how to achieve the objective (and do so efficiently, given the size of the actual data)!

Answer (score 0):

I expect that filtering a Pandas dataframe will be quicker than filtering a Networkx graph. So I would try the following:

Create a dictionary of nodes in the attribute table:

```
nodes_with_attributes = {x:0 for x in df_nodes['id'].values}
```

(Look ups in a dictionary are much faster than finding an element in a list, at the cost of memory.)

Then filter the edges:

```
df_filtered_edges = df_edges[
     (df_edges['id_from'].isin(nodes_with_attributes)& 
     (df_edges['id_to'].isin(nodes_with_attributes)]
```

Then you can make the filtered graph directly from the filtered dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift and helpful reply! That worked and ran efficiently. 

(Strangely, even when filtering the graph created from `df_filtered_edges` for, say, a particular value of att_1, eg like this
`nodes_subset = [x for x,y in G_filtered.nodes(data=True) if y['att_1']=='red']` 
I still get an error, but I'll figure it out.)